# Selecionar duas tabelas com diferentes colunas no ORACLE

Tags: oracle, select

Eu tenho três tabelas, uma chamada `ALUNO`, uma chamada`MATRICULA` e outra chamada `CLASSE` e eu preciso selecionar todos os alunos que sejam do sexo masculino e que pertençam a mesma classe de um aluno que tem um RGM específico.

As tabelas são :

**Tabela ALUNO**

```
  CREATE TABLE ALUNO(
    NR_RGM NUMBER(8),
    NM_NOME VARCHAR2(40) CONSTRAINT NOME_ALUNO_NN NOT NULL,
    NM_PAI VARCHAR2(40) CONSTRAINT PAI_ALUNO_NN NOT NULL,
    NM_MAE VARCHAR2(40) CONSTRAINT MAE_ALUNO_NN NOT NULL,
    DT_NASCIMENTO DATE CONSTRAINT DT_NASC_ALUNO_NN NOT NULL,
    ID_SEXO VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT SEXO_ALUNO_NN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ALUNO_NR_RGM_PK PRIMARY KEY (NR_RGM));
```

**Tabela MATRICULA :**

```
CREATE TABLE MATRICULA(
CD_CLASSE NUMBER(8),
NR_RGM NUMBER(8),
DT_MATRICULA DATE CONSTRAINT DATA_MATRICULA_NN NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT MATRICULA__CD_CLASSE_NR_RGM_PK PRIMARY KEY (CD_CLASSE,NR_RGM),
CONSTRAINT MATRICULA_CD_RGM_FK FOREIGN KEY(NR_RGM) REFERENCES ALUNO(NR_RGM),
CONSTRAINT MATRICULA_CD_CLASSE_FK FOREIGN KEY(CD_CLASSE) 
    REFERENCES CLASSE(CD_CLASSE));
```

**Tabela CLASSE :**

```
CREATE TABLE CLASSE(
CD_CLASSE NUMBER(8),
NR_ANOLETIVO NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT ANO_LETIVO_CLASSE_NN NOT NULL,
CD_ESCOLA NUMBER(6),
CD_GRAU NUMBER(2),
NR_SERIE NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT SERIE_CLASSE_NN NOT NULL,
TURMA VARCHAR2(2) CONSTRAINT TURMA_CLASSE_NN NOT NULL,
CD_PERIODO NUMBER(2),
CONSTRAINT CLASSE_PK PRIMARY KEY (CD_CLASSE),
CONSTRAINT GOIABAO FOREIGN KEY(CD_ESCOLA) 
      REFERENCES ESCOLA(CD_ESCOLA),
CONSTRAINT CLASSE_CD_CLASSE_FK FOREIGN KEY(CD_GRAU) REFERENCES GRAU(CD_GRAU),
CONSTRAINT CLASSE_CD_PERIODO_FK FOREIGN KEY(CD_PERIODO) REFERENCES PERIODO(CD_PERIODO),
CONSTRAINT CLASSE_ANO_LETIVO_CK CHECK(NR_ANOLETIVO > 2000));
```

Como eu poderia fazer isto ?

Por exemplo, para selecionar alunos da mesma sala do aluno de um RGM específico ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Matricula WHERE cd_classe = 
(SELECT cd_classe FROM matricula WHERE nr_rgm = '12150');
```

Mas como eu poderia fazer isto com duas colunas diferentes de duas tabelas diferentes ?

Comment: Como aluno se relaciona com classe ? Creio faltar um tabela.

Comment: Creio que eu coloquei na verdade a tabela errada, seria então a tabela Matricula que se relaciona com aluno através do nr_rgm como chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o que entendi, MATRICULA.nr_rgm referencia ALUNO.nr_rgm
e MATRICULA.cd_classe referencia CLASSE.cd_classe

então para retornar todos os alunos da mesma classe que possuem os mesmo NR_RGM e são do sexo masculino, faria algo assim:

```
select a.nome 
from aluno a
inner join matricula ma on (ma.nr_rgm = a.nr_rgm)
inner join classe c on (c.cd_classe = ma.cd_classe)
where a.nr_rgm = 12150 and a.id_sexo = 'M';
```

não testei, porque não tenho as tabelas criadas aqui, vê se isso ajuda de algum forma.

Comment: Ele retornou no final, o aluno do rgm de 12150 e não os outros que pertencem á mesma classe e que são do sexo masculino. Por que será que ocorreu isto ? Acho que tenha haver com o WHERE onde requer que o rgm seja igual a 12150, ou seja, ele só irá exibir o aluno deste rgm.

Comment: Nesse query ai, é para retornar somente os alunos de rgm = 12150 e s = 'M'. Verifica se tu estás criando as referências de primary key e foreign key nas tabelas corretamente, porque do jeito que está na sua pergunta e que eu entendi, isto bastaria. Se você colocar suas `create table ();` na pergunta, daria pra testar aqui.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei já os create table. E eu acho que ali você entendeu errado, seria na verdade para retornar todos alunos do sexo masculino e que pertençam á sala do aluno de RGM 12150. Enfim, desde já agradeço pela paciência por tentar responder.